# Is there a cleaner pythonic way to ignore calls to uninitialized attributes?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a class that gets used at multiple stations at out setup and each setup initializes a differnt set of equipments. As an example imaging the equipments I support are: house, car and bike.

```
class Site():
    def __init__(self, has_house, has_car, has_bike):
        self.house = init_house() if has_house else None
        self.car = init_car() if has_car else None
        self.bike = init_bike() if has_bike else None

    def switch_off(self):
        if self.house:
            self.house.switch_off()
        if self.car:
            self.car.switch_off()
        if self.bike:
            self.bike.switch_off()
```

Now, instead of having to check for each object. I am looking for a way to do something like this:

```
    def switch_off(self):
        self.house.switch_off()
        self.car.switch_off()
        self.bike.switch_off()
```

I expect the code to ignore the attributes that are not initialized. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getattr`:

```
def switch_off(self):
   for i in self.__dict__.values():
     getattr(i, 'switch_off', lambda :None)()
```

Or, without the loop, for clarity:

```
def switch_off(self):
  getattr(self.house, 'switch_off', lambda :None)()
  getattr(self.car, 'switch_off', lambda :None)()
  getattr(self.bike, 'switch_off', lambda :None)()
```

`getattr` provides the ability to pass an optional third parameter: a return value if the passed object does not have the desired attribute. In this case, if `house`, `car`, or `bike` is `None`, the `lambda` will be returned and called, instead of the original attribute `switch_off`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want a dictionary of attributes instead.

```
def __init__(self, has_house, has_car, has_bike):
    self.things = {}
    if has_house:
        self.things['house'] = init_house()
    if has_car:
        self.things['car'] = init_car()
    if has_bike:
        self.things['bike'] = init_bike()

def switch_off(self):
    for thing in self.things.values():
        thing.switch_off()
```